# Log Off only option in shutdown menu on Windows XP desktop

Tags: windows-xp

I was assigned to a few computers to interface with our IT department and get them to perform some upgrades on the systems to allow them to connect to the company network.  After they came and did their scripts and other changes, the systems should behave almost identical to any other standard company computer in terms of logging off/shutting down.

However, when going to Start -> Shut Down  (or CTRL+ALT+DELETE -> Shut Down), on these systems they now only have the option to log off a user and no other options a the shut down menu.

Does anybody know of a registry setting or somewhere to change this and allow for shutting down?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First, check the Group Policies at *`gpedit.msc`* - *User Configuration* - *Administrative templates* - *Start Menu and Taskbar* - **Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down command**.

Then, make sure the user has the privilege to shutdown the system (`SeShutdownPrivilege`).

(This might work: Open [ProcExp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), double-click on `explorer.exe`, and look for the privilege in Security tab.)

Comment: Googling SeShutdownPriveldge led me to the following:

Run -> secpol.msc -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignments

Here we find "Shut Down the System", I am lost from here however.  On my machine that is correctly configured it says Administrators and Users have this, however when I try to open it and add one, the menu is greyed out.

Now I try the same thing on one of the other systems and it only has Domain Admins with this ability and again, no visible way to modify this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Group Policy setting:
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > **Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down command**

If this is only applying to these few computers (and none others in the environment) check the local policy on these boxes:
Start > Run > gpedit.msc